# Why does a rainbow pattern appear, in a picture I took with my mobile in the mirror with flash?

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference, diffraction

I took a picture in the mirror with a flash (and in a flash). This was the result:

[image: mirror rainbow]

After a comment made below by @SuperfastJellyfish (indeed widening occurs), I made another picture (this time in the length of the mirror, which shows orientation doesn't matter):

[image]

I'm very curious about how this pattern came to be. Diffraction (refraction?) is involved as well as interference. Can it be explained in classical electrodynamics or do you need QED? I'm **almost** sure it can be explained classically. But I'm not sure...

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Almost certain that it is diffraction between partial reflection from the glass surface and the metal surface. Does the pattern make a bigger spread if you go closer to the mirror?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure it's diffraction.  More likely it's the result of positive vs. negative phase interference between some layers in the mirror -- at different angles the effective path length changes so different wavelengths (colors) get positive reinforcement.

If you look up "Newton's rings," you can get some basic intro to classical (wave-like) interference between surfaces.

Comment: Isn't that the same as diffraction?